# Parent and child messages in the same MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql

From the above table i wanted to extract a list with all messages where parent_id = 0 and sender_id or receiver_id is equal to my login id.

```
Table:Messages
id | parent_id | sender_id | receiver_id | subject | message | read
```

This was easy but i could not figure out how to count all child messages for messages WHERE parent_id = 0.

I tried this:

```
$my_messages = mysql_query("
  SELECT

messages.id, messages.sender_id, messages.receiver_id, messages.subject, messages.message, messages.minute,
 messages.hour, messages.day, messages.month, messages.year, COUNT(*) as 'mcount'
    FROM messages 
    LEFT JOIN messages AS mchild ON mchild.parent_id = messages.id 
    WHERE(messages.sender_id='$login_session' or messages.receiver_id='$login_session') 
    and messages.parent_id = '0'
    ORDER BY messages.year DESC, messages.month DESC, messages.day DESC, messages.hour DESC, messages.minute DESC

");
```

An additional thing i could not figure was how do i count all child+parent messages for each parent_id=0 WHERE read=1 if sender_id = $login_id or read=1 if receiver_id = $login_id

Here is an example:

```
Table:Messages
id | parent_id | sender_id | receiver_id | subject | message | read
 1 |         0 | Paul      | John        | Test    | Test    | 0
 2 |         0 | Paul      | Chris       | Test    | Test    | 0
 3 |         1 | john      | Paul        | Test    | Test    | 0
 4 |         1 | Paul      | John        | Test    | Test    | 1
 5 |         1 | John      | John        | Test    | Test    | 0
 6 |         0 | Paul      | Jack        | Test    | Test    | 0
```

Output:

```
ID:1 - 4 messages (1 parent+ 3 children), $unread=1 because read = 1 for  ID:4 wich is a child for ID:1
ID:2 - 1 message
ID:6 - 1 message
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a self join:

```
SELECT m1.id,
       COUNT(*) AS childCount
FROM messages m1
INNER JOIN
messages m2
    IN m1.id = m2.parent_id
WHERE '$login_session' IN(m1.sender_id,m1.receiver_id)
  AND m1.id = 0 -- you can remove this condition if you want all parents

GROUP BY m1.id
```

Typically the `COUNT` function is used with `GROUP BY`, the groups in this case being each parent.  But since you only want `parent_id` of zero, I added this to the `WHERE` clause, which will filter out every group but this one.  You may remove it if you want more information.

Comment: It's a good start but it will not output the parents with 0 children....I also changed . AND m1.id = 0  with AND m1.parent_id = 0 . Any idea about how to output all the parents not necessarly with parent_id = 0 ?

Comment: I changed INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN and works fine. (Assuming that there are no error in asigned parent_id). To be sure that it outputs only messages for $login_sesion i aded this  AND (m2.sender_id='$login_session' or m2.receiver_id='$login_session') but it will not display the parents with no children....back to the old problem...I will use your methond with LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN and i hope all is fine.